# How to discover the package a utility belongs to

Tags: apt, package-management

I installed CUDA using the official .deb form the NVIDIA homepage. But I ran into some trubles and wanted to redo the installation to ensure that every step along the way worked as expected.

Thus I `'apt-get purge cuda...'`

But now I still have nvcc which confuses me as I expected it to belong to the cuda package.

How do I figure out which package nvcc belongs to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check with `apt-file` because in your case `nvcc` is part of a package (`nvidia-cuda-toolkit`).

First you have to install `apt-file`

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Now start

```
apt-file search nvcc
```

or

```
apt-file search --regex /nvcc$
```

or

```
apt-file search $(which nvcc)
```

---

To check why the package `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` was installed use `aptitude`.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
aptitude why nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is `dpkg -S`.

So, to find out which package `zgrep` is in, try:

```
$ dpkg -S `which zgrep`
gzip: /bin/zgrep
```

This shows it's in the package `gzip`.

Of course you can just use the path to the file, e.g.:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/dict/words
diversion by dictionaries-common from: /usr/share/dict/words
diversion by dictionaries-common to: /usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common
dictionaries-common, wamerican: /usr/share/dict/words
```

This incidentally shows a more complex example.

Answer (score 1):

`apt` uses dpkg as back-end to install many apps, and for dpkg there is a `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory , where there's many `*.info` files; these contain information on each and every file that came with a package.

Thus you can do `grep -i --color 'nvcc' /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list` . That may generate a pretty large list, however, so to narrow it down we can use `which` utility.

`which` locates a particular binary/executable file. For instance,

```
xieerqi:$ grep $(which gnome-terminal) /var/lib/dpkg/info>
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-terminal.list:/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-terminal.list:/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

This tells grep to take full path to `gnome-terminal` executable, and find which package has installed it.  In this case the package was `gnome-terminal`.

A not so obvious case would be `nm-tool`

```
xieerqi:$ grep $(which nm-tool) /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/network-manager.list:/usr/bin/nm-tool
```

We thus know, it belongs to `network-manager` package

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-cache search nvcc`

returns:

`libnvvm2 - NVIDIA CUDA Compiler NVVM runtime library
nvidia-cuda-toolkit - NVIDIA CUDA toolkit`

apt-cache should already be installed on your system.